Is it possible to force picocli to not overwrite a value set in a constructor when there is no option given on cli?
Consider the following MWE:
import picocli.CommandLine;
import static picocli.CommandLine.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MWE {
  static class Tar {
    @Option(names = { "-f", "--file" }, paramLabel = "ARCHIVE", description = "the archive file")
    Optional<File> archive;

    public Tar() {
      archive = Optional.of(new File("helloworld"));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Tar tar = new Tar();
    System.out.println(tar.archive);
    new CommandLine(tar).parseArgs(args);
    System.out.println(tar.archive);
  }
}

The picocli documentation claims that defaultValue has a default value of "__no_default_value__", which I am interpreting to imply that it will not change the value of any field if there is no flag given on the command line.
Thus, when I invoke this program with no arguments, I expect the following output:
Optional[helloworld]
Optional[helloworld]

However, the actual output I get is:
Optional[helloworld]
Optional.empty

It appears that the parseArguments call has set archive to Optional.empty despite the lack of arguments given on the command line and the lack of explicit setting for the default value of this option.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior and get the expected output?
Note: I'm asking about this because I want to be able to set overridable default values in the subclass of an options class, and subclass constructor seems like a reasonable place to put it.

I raised an issue and the author ended up changing this behavior in the latest main branch, so the example now has the expected behavior described in the question.

 When Picocli sets up your command class, it resets all fields to default. For an Optional field, this means Optional.empty(). This reset occurs before it processes the command line arguments. If you don't supply a command line value for an option linked to an Optional field, that field stays at Optional.empty() even if the constructor previously set a default value.
 This ensures that Optional fields accurately represent whether an option was provided by the user. However, this setup overwrites any default values set in the constructor for Optional fields before parsing arguments. Sadly, Picocli lacks a direct method to tell apart situations where an option was "not provided" from those where it was "provided without a value" for Optional fields.
There are a few workarounds that I can think of for this though:
Use a String (or another type) and manually wrap it in an Optional
public class MWE {
  static class Tar {
    @Option(names = {"-f", "--file"}, paramLabel = "ARCHIVE",
        description = "the archive file")
    private File archive = new File("helloworld"); // <-- set default value directly

    public Optional<File> getArchive() {
      return Optional.ofNullable(archive);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // no changes
  }
}

A Post-parse check
You can adjust your main method or wherever you handle the parsed arguments to check if the Optional field is empty and if so, set it to your default value:
psvm(s[] a) {
  Tar tar_sauce = new Tar();
  
  new CommandLine(tar_sauce).parseArgs(args);

  if (!tar_sauce.archive.isPresent()) { // <-- check if the field is empty,
    tar_sauce.archive = Optional.of(new File("jelloworld")); // <-- and set the default value after parsing
  }
}

Custom setter
The last workaround I could think up would involve removing the Optional from the field and handling the Optional logic through a custom setter that Picocli will not directly use
public class MWE {
  static class Tar {
    private File archive = new File("helloworld");
    @Option(names = {"-f", "--file"}, paramLabel = "ARCHIVE",
        description = "the archive file")
    private void
    setArchive(File file) {
      this.archive = file;
    }

    public Optional<File> getArchive() {
      return Optional.ofNullable(archive);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // no changes
  }
}

with these 3 ways you directly manage switching to and from Optional, giving you control over default values, while ensuring you follow Picocli's parsing rules.They may not be 100% perfect as I don't use picocli frequently, but after reading the docs, they should (hopefully) work :)Feel free to leave me any comments if something is wrong/incorrect.
